# Transform a list comprehension to simple for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, permutation

I have a list comprehension that returns the list of all possible permutations given the fact that the input contains all unique numbers.

```
nums = [1,2,3]
ans = [[]]
for x in nums:
    ans = [items + [n] for items in ans for n in nums if (n not in items)]
print(ans)

> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I tried to write for loop for this all follows:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
ans = [[]]

for x in nums:
    for items in ans:
        for n in nums:
            if n not in items:
                items.append(n)
print(ans)
```

However, this does not give me the required output. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: No idea. I don't understand why people do this without even suggesting changes or edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[items + [n] for items in ans for n in nums if (n not in items)]
```

Let's break this down, going from right to left.

```
for items in ans:
    for n in nums:
        if n not in items:
```

Then you just create a list and add these `items + [n]` in them

```
result = []
for items in ans:
    for n in nums:
        if n not in items:
            result.append(items + [n])
```

Now this whole thing is being executed from inside another loop `for x in nums`. So you have:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
ans = [[]]

for x in nums:
    result = []
    for items in ans:
        for n in nums:
            if n not in items:
                result.append(items + [n])
    ans = result
```